# How to draw "crisp and sharp" lines on an low resolution ImageView?

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, paint, resolution

I am drawing lines on an ImageView by doing something like this:

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
Bitmap duplicateBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBitmap.getWidth(),imageBitmap.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

Canvas targetCanvas = new Canvas(duplicateBitmap);
targetCanvas.drawBitmap(imageBitmap,0,0,null);
Paint paint = new Paint();
targetCanvas.drawLine(0f,100f, imageBitmap.getWidth(),100f,paint);
imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),duplicateBitmap));
```

This works fine [when the Image has a decent or good resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etunr.png).

But it looks like this [when the image has a low resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc2DQ.png). (Which is a bad experience)

Now, how do I draw sharp and crisp lines on a low res image?

For once I thought I should mask the image with a high res canvas. But then I was clueless about how to proceed with this idea. Also, this might be a memory inefficient implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out with @D. Karchnak's guidance...

> Let's say your phone's screen is 1080x1920, you create a layout with a
> fullscreen ImageView, therefore this ImageView is also 1080x1920. Now
> you load a .png image as a BitmapDrawable. This PNG image has a
> resolution of 400x400, therefore the bitmap inside BitmapDrawable is
> also 400x400. If you draw this "small" bitmap to a fullscreen
> ImageView, it will get blurred out, because of low resolution. If you
> draw a line to this 400x400 bitmap, this line will also get blurred
> out. That's also why it works with decent or good resolution.

All I need to do is, create a subclass of android's ImageView and then shift my drawing logic into the onDraw method (of course after overriding it). Like so:

```
public class FineLineImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

    public FineLineImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public FineLineImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public FineLineImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // logic for drawing goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really need a Bitmap with the result, make sure the duplicateBitmap is the same size as the ImageView you're drawing it with.

If all you need is to draw a grid over a ImageView, I'd create a custom class, extending ImageView. Override it's `draw(Canvas)` method and use provided `Canvas` to draw the grid.

Code for this would look something like this:

```
class GridImageView(context: Context....): ImageView(...) {
    val gridPaint = Paint() //Set color, strokeWidth etc...

    @Override
    fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
       super.onDraw(canvas)

       //TODO - complex grid drawing here...
       canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint)
    }
}
```

Comment: The line

```Bitmap duplicateBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBitmap.getWidth(),imageBitmap.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);```

Already justifies that the duplicateBitmap is the same size as the ImageView I'm drawing with.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure tbh, but I don't think it does. It sets the newly created bitmap's size (`duplicateBitmap`) to the size of bitmap used by ImageView's bitmap drawable, which is the size of the original bitmap image.

Comment: So how do you think that the bitmap's size is related to drawing "crisp" lines on an image?

Comment: Let's say your phone's screen is 1080x1920, you create a layout with a fullscreen ImageView, therefore this ImageView is also 1080x1920. Now you load a .png image as a BitmapDrawable. This PNG image has a resolution of 400x400, therefore the bitmap inside BitmapDrawable is also 400x400. If you draw this "small" bitmap to a fullscreen ImageView, it will get blurred out, because of low resolution. If you draw a line to this 400x400 bitmap, this line will also get blurred out. That's also why it works with decent or good resolution.

Comment: Damn, such an amazing explanation @D. Karchnak. Hats off!! So what do you think could be a possible solution for my use case?

Comment: As I can't be sure if the user always loads a high res image into the imageView. And yes,  I need to draw grids on an ImageView but the logic to draw grids is very complex... could you please elaborate on "How I can extend ImageView class and override onDraw method to meet my requirements of the drawing logic?"

Comment: I've edited the answer, I'm not at the computer right now, so it's more of a pseudo code. You basically extend ImageView, let it draw it's image and then draw the grid on top of it. Unfortunately I won't be nearby a computer for 2 more days, but if you don't solve it by then I can provide you a fully working source code solving this issue. :)